# How to implement custom dot shaped Tab indicator with custom color in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, tabbar

I want to implement **Dot shaped tab indicator**. (i.e, Small circle) like the image below with custom color.

[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfriK.jpg)

Please do help on this.

Comment: Use a custom widget extending Decoration.

Comment: how to implement this

Comment: Will post brief answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a separate widget with color & radius as a parameter to achieve this.

[As Referred from here](https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-custom-tab-indicator-for-tabbar-d72bbc6c9d0c)

indicator parameter expects a Decoration so we should create a **BoxPainter**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CircleTabIndicator extends Decoration {
 final BoxPainter _painter;

 CircleTabIndicator({@required Color color, @required double radius})
    : _painter = _CirclePainter(color, radius);

 @override
 BoxPainter createBoxPainter([onChanged]) => _painter;
}

class _CirclePainter extends BoxPainter {
 final Paint _paint;
 final double radius;

 _CirclePainter(Color color, this.radius)
    : _paint = Paint()
  ..color = color
  ..isAntiAlias = true;

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration cfg) {
   final Offset circleOffset =
      offset + Offset(cfg.size.width / 2, cfg.size.height - radius - 5);
   canvas.drawCircle(circleOffset, radius, _paint);
 }
```

}

**And use it As**

```
 indicator: CircleTabIndicator(color: Colors.white, radius: 3),
```

Answer (score 3):

*If you want to ease your work, then you can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/tab_indicator_styler) package, and by using this `package` you can customize the tab `indicator`.*

**Here** *Below is the Example `Code` for the same which I have used in one of my project, and will get your achieve the desired result with a dot `indicator`.*

See the `indicator` section in below Code:-

```
  buildTabBarContent() {
    return TabBar(
      isScrollable: true,
      labelColor: Colors.black,
      indicator: DotIndicator(
        color: Colors.black,
        distanceFromCenter: 16,
        radius: 3,
        paintingStyle: PaintingStyle.fill,
      ),
      tabs: [
        Tab(
          text: "All",
        ),
        Tab(text: "Football"),
        Tab(
          text: "Tennis",
        ),
        Tab(text: "Basketball"),
        Tab(text: "Cricket"),
        Tab(text: "Cricket"),
        Tab(text: "Cricket"),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: No Worries @karthika